# Как лучше создать dict-like класс с составным ключом?

Tags: python, ооп, python-3.x

Задача в следующем:

1. имеется класс, имеющий 4 свойства, 2 из которых "только для чтения"
2. нужно создать второй класс (в каком-то роде dict-like), состоящий из последовательности экземпляров первого класса и в котором должен использоваться составной ключ из вышеупомянутых двух readonly-свойств. Как сделать это лучше?

Надеюсь, объяснил более или менее понятно

Пробовал сделать, реализовав для первого класса методы `__eq__` и `__hash__`, а во втором хранил экземпляры первого класса во множестве. Примерно так: [gist](https://gist.github.com/become-iron/61eff7874af0a6c6211810348185f17f). Но мне не особо это нравится: создание множества, конечно, происходит по "составному ключу", но получить значение по этому ключу нельзя

Смотрел библиотеку `collections`, но тоже не нашёл подходящего

Comment: Можно пример, как будет использоваться второй класс?

Comment: @Pavel Вообще, нужно будет реализовать во втором классе, например, следующие методы: получение элемента по составному ключу; поиск элементов по одному или обоим свойствам, входящих в ключ; удаление элементов по ключу; нужно будет иметь возможность складывать экземпляры первого и второго класса.

Comment: Например, есть класс Obj с полями key1, key2, val1, val2, а второй класс называется Seq. Он должен вот так http://pastebin.com/mAw460JZ работать?

Comment: @Pavel Да, можно так представить необходимый функционал. Сейчас я уже решил проблему некоторым способом — можно глянуть ниже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено было примерно так:

```py
class Trp:
    def __init__(self, prefix, name, value, comment):
        self.prefix = prefix  # readonly
        self.name = name  # readonly
        self.value = value
        self.comment = comment

class TrpStr:
    def __init__(self, *trps):
        self._trps = {}
        for trp in trps:
            self._trps.update({(trp.prefix, trp.name): trp})
```

Решение, конечно, не идеальное